# Exclude subdocument in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

Given document structure like this:

```
{
    "a": "vala",
    "b": "valb",
    "c": {
        "ca": "valca",
        "cb": "valcb"
    },
    "x": {
        "xa": "valxa",
        "xb": "valxb"
    },
    "d": "vald",
    ...
}
```

How to construct a query that whould return documents that have some "search_value" in any field of the document outside the "x" subdocument.

Documents like this **would** be included:
{"a": "search_value"},
{"c": {"cb": "search_value"},
{"ggg": "search_value", "x": {"xa": "valxa"}}
{"ggg": "search_value", "x": {"xa": "search_value"}}

Documents like this **would not** be included:
{"a": "vala"},
{"a": "vala", "x": {"xa": "search_value"}}
{"x": "search_value"}

Comment: are you always excluding the x field? If so, why do you index it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ***highlight query*** to get your hits, and use wildcards to highlight all hits fields. so you need to filter ***x*** by your self.

For example, search value in field ***x***:

```
{
    "fields": [],
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "x": "search_value"
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags" : [""],
        "post_tags" : [""],
        "fields": {
            "*": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thaks! Unfortunately I don't know the list of fields (a, b, c, ...) in advance.

Comment: @Tomek I have updated my answer, and I use `wildcards` to highlight all hitted fields. but this way it will also contain `x` field. Hope it can help you.